# error while installing pip for windows 8 (hebrew)

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip

Hi Im trying to install pip on my pc - windows 8 in hebrew.

I installed python 2.7. I added python to my path.

I ran some random printing in python file and its work. so python is ok.

when i try to install get-pip.py I get this error:

```
C:\Users\yogi>python get-pip.py
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\yogi\appdata\local\temp\tmppowtnc\pip.zip\pip\basecommand.py",
line 232, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "c:\users\yogi\appdata\local\temp\tmppowtnc\pip.zip\pip\commands\install.
py", line 339, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder)
  File "c:\users\yogi\appdata\local\temp\tmppowtnc\pip.zip\pip\req\req_set.py",
line 235, in prepare_files
    req_to_install, self.upgrade)
  File "c:\users\yogi\appdata\local\temp\tmppowtnc\pip.zip\pip\index.py", line 3
05, in find_requirement
    page = self._get_page(main_index_url, req)
  File "c:\users\yogi\appdata\local\temp\tmppowtnc\pip.zip\pip\index.py", line 7
83, in _get_page
    return HTMLPage.get_page(link, req, session=self.session)
  File "c:\users\yogi\appdata\local\temp\tmppowtnc\pip.zip\pip\index.py", line 8
72, in get_page
    "Cache-Control": "max-age=600",
  File "c:\users\yogi\appdata\local\temp\tmppowtnc\pip.zip\pip\_vendor\requests\
sessions.py", line 473, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\yogi\appdata\local\temp\tmppowtnc\pip.zip\pip\download.py", lin
e 365, in request
    return super(PipSession, self).request(method, url, *args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\yogi\appdata\local\temp\tmppowtnc\pip.zip\pip\_vendor\requests\
sessions.py", line 461, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "c:\users\yogi\appdata\local\temp\tmppowtnc\pip.zip\pip\_vendor\requests\
sessions.py", line 610, in send
    r.content
  File "c:\users\yogi\appdata\local\temp\tmppowtnc\pip.zip\pip\_vendor\requests\
models.py", line 728, in content
    self._content = bytes().join(self.iter_content(CONTENT_CHUNK_SIZE)) or bytes
()
  File "c:\users\yogi\appdata\local\temp\tmppowtnc\pip.zip\pip\_vendor\requests\
models.py", line 653, in generate
    for chunk in self.raw.stream(chunk_size, decode_content=True):
  File "c:\users\yogi\appdata\local\temp\tmppowtnc\pip.zip\pip\_vendor\requests\
packages\urllib3\response.py", line 256, in stream
    data = self.read(amt=amt, decode_content=decode_content)
  File "c:\users\yogi\appdata\local\temp\tmppowtnc\pip.zip\pip\_vendor\requests\
packages\urllib3\response.py", line 186, in read
    data = self._fp.read(amt)
  File "c:\users\yogi\appdata\local\temp\tmppowtnc\pip.zip\pip\_vendor\cachecont
rol\filewrapper.py", line 54, in read
    self.__callback(self.__buf.getvalue())
  File "c:\users\yogi\appdata\local\temp\tmppowtnc\pip.zip\pip\_vendor\cachecont
rol\controller.py", line 213, in cache_response
    self.serializer.dumps(request, response, body=body),
  File "c:\users\yogi\appdata\local\temp\tmppowtnc\pip.zip\pip\download.py", lin
e 268, in set
    return super(SafeFileCache, self).set(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\yogi\appdata\local\temp\tmppowtnc\pip.zip\pip\_vendor\cachecont
rol\caches\file_cache.py", line 83, in set
    with FileLock(name) as lock:
  File "c:\users\yogi\appdata\local\temp\tmppowtnc\pip.zip\pip\_vendor\lockfile\
mkdirlockfile.py", line 18, in __init__
    LockBase.__init__(self, path, threaded, timeout)
  File "c:\users\yogi\appdata\local\temp\tmppowtnc\pip.zip\pip\_vendor\lockfile\
__init__.py", line 189, in __init__
    hash(self.path)))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ntpath.py", line 84, in join
    result_path = result_path + p_path
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 0: ordinal
not in range(128)
```

any help would appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thought you may wanna try these since you are installing it in Hebrew.

1.) Open path `"C:\Python27\Lib\"` and search for python file "`mimetypes.py`".

2.) Open and Edit that file. Search for line "`default_encoding = sys.getdefaultencoding()`"

3.) And add these lines before the searched line in (step 2):

```
if sys.getdefaultencoding() != 'gbk':
  reload(sys)
  sys.setdefaultencoding('gbk')
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked. but now when i try 'pip install mechanize' I get the same error - so the solution is to add these lines every time?

Answer (score 0):

The UnicodeDecode Error might be because you are using wrong version of get-pip.py.
All the strings in Python3 are unicode by default, but in Python2 it is not so.

If you are trying to use get-pip of Python3 with Python2, it might likely be the cause of your error.Try checking for/ obtaining the correct version! :)